# How to install OS packages using yum?

Tags: rhel, software-installation, yum

I need to install below packages:

```
gcc:   gcc-c++-4.4.7-3.el6.x86_64
Flex:  flex-2.5.35-8.el6.x86_64
Bison: bison-2.4.1-5.el6.x86_64
Glib:  glib2-devel-2.22.5-7.el6.x86_64   &  glibc-devel-2.12-1.107.el6_4.2.x86_64
Pcre:  pcre-7.8-6.el6.x86_64  & pcre-devel-7.8-6.el6.x86_64
logrotate:  logrotate-3.7.8-16.el6.x86_64
sendmail:  sendmail-8.14.4-8.el6.x86_64 & sendmail-cf-8.14.4-8.el6.noarch
```

using `yum` from below repositories.

---

```
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: package_upload, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
repo id                                                                                        repo name                                                                                       status
!RBC_RBC-Tools-RHEL7_rbc-tools-rhel-7Server-x86_64-rpms                                        rbc-tools-rhel-7Server-x86_64-rpms                                                                   9
!rhel-7-server-extras-rpms/x86_64                                                              Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server - Extras (RPMs)                                                  747
!rhel-7-server-optional-rpms/7Server/x86_64                                                    Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server - Optional (RPMs)                                             13,201
!rhel-7-server-rpms/7Server/x86_64                                                             Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server (RPMs)                                                        18,022
!rhel-7-server-satellite-tools-6.1-rpms/x86_64                                                 Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.1 (for RHEL 7 Server) (RPMs)                                              86
!rhel-7-server-supplementary-rpms/7Server/x86_64                                               Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server - Supplementary (RPMs)                                           270
repolist: 32,335
```

---

But, I get below error:

```
# yum install gcc-c++-4.4.7-3.el6.x86_64
Loaded plugins: package_upload, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
RBC_RBC-Tools-RHEL7_rbc-tools-rhel-7Server-x86_64-rpms                                                                                                                        | 1.8 kB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-extras-rpms                                                                                                                                                     | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-optional-rpms                                                                                                                                                   | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-rpms                                                                                                                                                            | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-satellite-tools-6.1-rpms                                                                                                                                        | 2.1 kB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-supplementary-rpms                                                                                                                                              | 2.3 kB  00:00:00
No package gcc-c++-4.4.7-3.el6.x86_64 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

---

How to resolve this error? Do I need to add some more repositories? if yes, how?

Comment: You appear to be attempting to install a g++ *EL6* versioned package on a system with RHEL7 repositories... Perhaps you'd be more successful just attempting to install `gcc-c++`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking to install GCC, all you need to do is `yum install gcc-c++` it will get its dependencies if you have access to them, or it will error out. For the rest of your packages, just put in the text name before <name>-<version number>. `yum install flex bison sendmail` just see if the other packages get installed as dependencies, if not go back and install them too using `yum install <name>`.

If you need more help to understand `yum`, just type `man yum` for more references and details about `yum`.

```
[root@server thebtm]# yum install gcc                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 * base: mirror.its.sfu.ca                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 * epel: muug.ca                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 * extras: muug.ca                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 * ius: mirrors.kernel.org                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 * updates: mirror.its.sfu.ca
Package gcc-4.8.5-28.el7_5.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Example of when its not installed:

```
[root@fada2474faea iop]# yum install gcc-c++
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                                                                                  |  16 kB  00:00:00     
 * base: mirror.its.sfu.ca
 * epel: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
 * extras: mirror.its.sfu.ca
 * ius: mirrors.kernel.org
 * updates: mirror.its.sfu.ca
base                                                                                                                                                                                                                  | 3.6 kB  00:00:00     
epel                                                                                                                                                                                                                  | 3.2 kB  00:00:00     
extras                                                                                                                                                                                                                | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
ius                                                                                                                                                                                                                   | 2.3 kB  00:00:00     
updates                                                                                                                                                                                                               | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
(1/2): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                                                                                                                                                                                         | 933 kB  00:00:00     
(2/2): epel/x86_64/primary                                                                                                                                                                                            | 3.6 MB  00:00:00     
epel                                                                                                                                                                                                                             12647/12647
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.8.5-28.el7_5.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++-devel = 4.8.5-28.el7_5.1 for package: gcc-c++-4.8.5-28.el7_5.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: gcc = 4.8.5-28.el7_5.1 for package: gcc-c++-4.8.5-28.el7_5.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpfr.so.4()(64bit) for package: gcc-c++-4.8.5-28.el7_5.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpc.so.3()(64bit) for package: gcc-c++-4.8.5-28.el7_5.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gcc.x86_64 0:4.8.5-28.el7_5.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: cpp = 4.8.5-28.el7_5.1 for package: gcc-4.8.5-28.el7_5.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-devel >= 2.2.90-12 for package: gcc-4.8.5-28.el7_5.1.x86_64
---> Package libmpc.x86_64 0:1.0.1-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package libstdc++-devel.x86_64 0:4.8.5-28.el7_5.1 will be installed
---> Package mpfr.x86_64 0:3.1.1-4.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cpp.x86_64 0:4.8.5-28.el7_5.1 will be installed
---> Package glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.17-222.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers = 2.17-222.el7 for package: glibc-devel-2.17-222.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers for package: glibc-devel-2.17-222.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.17-222.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-headers >= 2.2.1 for package: glibc-headers-2.17-222.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-headers for package: glibc-headers-2.17-222.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:3.10.0-862.11.6.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                     Arch                                               Version                                                            Repository                                           Size
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 gcc-c++                                                     x86_64                                             4.8.5-28.el7_5.1                                                   updates                                             7.2 M
Installing for dependencies:
 cpp                                                         x86_64                                             4.8.5-28.el7_5.1                                                   updates                                             5.9 M
 gcc                                                         x86_64                                             4.8.5-28.el7_5.1                                                   updates                                              16 M
 glibc-devel                                                 x86_64                                             2.17-222.el7                                                       base                                                1.1 M
 glibc-headers                                               x86_64                                             2.17-222.el7                                                       base                                                678 k
 kernel-headers                                              x86_64                                             3.10.0-862.11.6.el7                                                updates                                             7.1 M
 libmpc                                                      x86_64                                             1.0.1-3.el7                                                        base                                                 51 k
 libstdc++-devel                                             x86_64                                             4.8.5-28.el7_5.1                                                   updates                                             1.5 M
 mpfr                                                        x86_64                                             3.1.1-4.el7                                                        base                                                203 k

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+8 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 40 M
Installed size: 84 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: n
Exiting on user command
Your transaction was saved, rerun it with:
 yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx.2018-08-16.23-11.GY0gCD.yumtx
```

Comment: What about pcre & logrotate & glib2? gcc has only installed glibc

Comment: @overexchange we are not expected to guide you in every (simple and) small detail. You also have to do your end of work. Think over things a bit, and try them to get used to them.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro ok I will try

Comment: This answer would align more closely to the OP's situation if you demonstrated with the `gcc-c++` package.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, updated for the instance of not installed.